# Einstein "quantum leaps" into young Japanese girl

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, alternate-history, nuclear-weapons

I recall a short story I read in the 80's or 90's (might be older than that).  The premise is that Albert Einstein (pretty sure it was him, might've been another scientist associated with the Manhattan Project) is racked with guilt about his involvement, and spends the rest of his life secretly trying to invent time travel in order to go back and prevent it.  In the end, he succeeds, only it appears to modern observers as though he has simply died of old age.  In reality, his consciousness gets sent back in time, and Quantum Leap-style, he finds himself in the body of a young girl, 10-12 or so.  At first he's delighted that he has a whole new life to live and discover new things (and the novelty of being female is remarked on).  It's not revealed until near the end that she is a villager in Hiroshima (maybe Nagasaki?) and it is days (or possibly less) before the bomb drops.  He tries to warn everyone, but nobody will believe him/her because he's just a little girl, so he is unable to do anything.  I think it's left as a matter of interpretation whether he has actually traveled back in time, or if all of the experiences were just flashing through his head at the end of his life.

The ending feels kind of "Twilight Zone" twist to me, but I'm pretty sure it was text and not a visual medium, since it would be hard to hide the fact that the girl and everyone else around her are Japanese.  She and all of the other characters are never given names (I believe her parents are just "mother" and "father" or something like that), nor are there any obvious clues that the past part of the story takes place in Japan until the reveal near the end.  The dialogue is all implied and not explicitly written (presumably because they would be talking in Japanese).  No physical descriptions of the people or the environment are given - it's deliberately left vague in order to make the twist at the end work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Einstein's only involvement with the Manhattan Project (and the bomb in general) was the letter to Roosevelt that helped get government backing for the project.

Comment: @DavidW He later said that was a mistake. However, he also didn't like the "spooky action at a distance" inherent in this question.

Comment: @DavidW Hey, I didn't write the story, I'm just remembering some details.  I'm not even 100% sure if it was Einstein or someone else - maybe Feynman?  The plausibility of the story is not the question though.  I just know it exists somewhere.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I'm not saying that you're definitely wrong, or casting aspersions on your memory.  I'm just making a note to other searchers that might help; I didn't find anything applicable for Oppenheimer either.

Comment: If it helps any, I think the author was Japanese, at least ethnically.  But the story was definitely in English when I read it - though that was possibly a translation.